# How to use filters in 3 columns (Ionic)

Tags: html, search, filter, ionic-framework

I want to create a 3 column (div) list using Ionic. And I want to apply a filter while the user write something. I wrote the code below, but the code only list 3 results. Can anyone help?

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <lablel class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchQuery" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33" ng-repeat="contact in contactList | filter:searchQuery">
          {{contact.nome}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

OBS: the code is filtering right. I have 150+ results, and when I don't write anything on search it should list all results, but only list 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

everyone.

I solved my problem. Thats what i did:

My ionic receives an JSON file from an external URL (my site). This JSON file is generated by an MYSQL query. I used the PHP function array_chunk in query:

```
$SQL = mysql_query("...");

$CHUNK = array_chunk($SQL, 3);

print json_encode($CHUNK);
```

So, in the HTML code i did this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
      <ion-content>
        <div>
          <lablel class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchQuery" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in contactList">
            <div class="col col-33" ng-repeat="item in chunk | filter:searchQuery">
              {{item.nome}}
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Wordked like a charm.